# How to create Blob URL from video and assign to video source?

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video

I am showing the video on the web page. But I want end-user should not download the video from the browser. I want to prevent the download video.

My question is can we create a buffer array in PHP? and using Javascript create Blob URL from buffer array. Then I can assign the Blob URL to video tag.

Videos are not in the same domain. It Is on the CDN.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to get a byte chunk from php,

```
$CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024; //buffer size in bytes
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

$start = $_GET['position'];

//point to last serve position
fseek($handle, $start);

//read and send byte chunk
$buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
echo $buffer;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

On the javascript size call this php script using xhr (ajax) and push the byte array to video element stream.

```
//using media source api. Check for browser compatibility
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', mediaSourceOpen);

var mimeType = 'video/mp4';
var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);

//get the vide element and attach source
var player = document.getElementById('player');
player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

var start = 0;
function mediaSourceOpen() {
  fetchData();
}

function fetchData(){
  fetch('URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT?start=' + start)
  .then(response => {
     return response.arrayBuffer()
  }).then(buffer => {
     if(buffer.byteLength > 0)
        start += buffer.byteLength;
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
        fetchData();
     }
  });
}
```

**Code doesn't include error handling. Just the main scenario. Treat it as a pseudo code and do your implementation. I'll try to post a workign sample also**